# Replacement for > and < operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, operators

Is there a replacement for the greater/less than operator (<,>)?

I am trying to sort my array on descending order here but i cannot use the operators in the environment i am working in.

Here is the code that i use to order my array with strings in it on descending order:

```
// descending order
animals.sort(function (a, b) {
if (a > b) {
    return -1;
}
if (b > a) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
});
console.log(animals);
// ["elephant", "dog", "cat", "bee", "ant"]
```

Comment: "but i cannot use the operators in the environment i am working in" — why on earth not?

Comment: `.sort().reverse()`?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `a &gt; b`?

Comment: There's nothing like [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `localeCompare` function

```js
var animals = ["dog", "cat", "ant", "bee", "elephant"];

animals.sort(function (a, b) {
  return -a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(animals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not about the *operators*, but the characters, you can try

```
animals.sort(new Function("a", "b", "return (b \u003e a) - (a \x3e b)"));
```

where `\u003e` and `\x3e` are escape sequences for the `>` character in an `eval`ed string.

Answer (score -1):

use sort method of array

```
var animals = ["elephant", "dog", "cat", "bee", "ant"];
animals.sort();
```